# QML application displays black screen

Tags: android, qml, qtquick2

I am a beginner in QML but I dont think I am doing much in the project but still I am getting a black screen when i run this application on Android device.

Main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Rectangle {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            Qt.quit()
        }
    }

    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

Button .QML

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: mainbtn
    property alias text: lable.text
    width: 165
    height: 50
    radius: 2
    border.width: 2
    Text {
        id: lable
        font.bold: true
        font.pointSize: 17
        width: parent.width
        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            console.log("1")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I realized the mistake that I did. I made the application using Qt quick controls application instead of using Qt Qucik Application

Comment: They should both work, so I doubt that that was the issue.

Comment: I dont know but I kept on trying with the same code again and again for hours. Finally before giving up I decided to try one more time and I made sure that while creating a new project I did create it using Qt quick application and it worked. Since it started working I thought of reporting it here @Mitch

Answer (score 0):

try use [ApplicationWindow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-applicationwindow.html) as root Component

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("MyApp")
    Ractangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: “yellow”
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope still black color. And i am using a `property alias text: lable.text` and when I am using this alias in main it gives me an error invalid propertyname